# Calling the function and ending the loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, calling-convention

I'm stuck with calling the `getGallons` function. I tried to return the `gallons`, `acrearea`, and `snowdepth`, but the results always end with 0. I also want to end the loop with "Enter the depth (inches) of snow that has fallen (or -1 to exit): " without the `break`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double getGallons(float snowdepth);

int main()
{
    float snowdepth, acrearea;
    double gallons;
    
    cout << "Enter the depth (inches) of snow that has fallen (or -1 to exit): ";
    cin >> snowdepth;
    cout << "Enter the area (acres) that the snow covers: ";
    cin >> acrearea;
    cout << "This amount of snow equals " << gallons << " gallons of water." << endl << endl;
    
    
    
    while (snowdepth > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter the depth (inches) of snow that has fallen (or -1 to exit): ";
        cin >> snowdepth;
        cout << "Enter the area (acres) that the snow covers: ";
        cin >> acrearea;
        cout << "This amount of snow equals " << gallons << " gallons of water." << endl << endl;
    }    
    
    cout << "Enjoy the snow!" << endl;
    cout << "Press any key to continue...." << endl;
    
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(1);
    
    gallons = getGallons(snowdepth);

    return 0;
}

double getGallons(float snowdepth)
{
    float acrearea;
    double gallons;
    const int WATER_GALLONS = 27154;
    gallons = snowdepth * acrearea * WATER_GALLONS;
    
    return gallons;
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `acrearea` in the `getGallons` function. That results in undefined behavior.

Comment: You are trying to print "gallons" before you have computed it.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double getGallons(float snowdepth, float acrearea);

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        float snowdepth, acrearea;

        cout << "Enter the depth (inches) of snow that has fallen (or -1 to exit): ";
        cin >> snowdepth;
        if( snowdepth < 0 )
            break;

        cout << "Enter the area (acres) that the snow covers: ";
        cin >> acrearea;

        double gallons = getGallons(snowdepth,acrearea);

        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(1);

        cout << "This amount of snow equals " << gallons << " gallons of water.\n\n";
    }    

    cout << "Enjoy the snow!" << endl;

    return 0;
}

double getGallons(float snowdepth, float acrearea)
{
    const int WATER_GALLONS = 27154;
    return snowdepth * acrearea * WATER_GALLONS;
}
```

Comment: The OP said: "*I also want to end the loop ... without the `break`*"

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the user's input for `acrearea`, using an unrelated and uninitialized `acrearea` to calculate the gallons.

Also, you are not calculating the `gallons` at all for each set of user inputs. You are calculating the `gallons` only after the user has opted to end the loop.

For that matter, you are giving the user the option to exit on the very first input, but you are not respecting if the user actually chooses to exit on the first input.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

double getGallons(float snowdepth, float acrearea);

int main()
{
    float snowdepth, acrearea;
    double gallons;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the depth (inches) of snow that has fallen (or -1 to exit): ";
        cin >> snowdepth;
        if (snowdepth > 0) {
            cout << "Enter the area (acres) that the snow covers: ";
            cin >> acrearea;

            gallons = getGallons(snowdepth, acrearea);

            cout << "This amount of snow equals " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1) << gallons << " gallons of water." << endl << endl;
       }
    }
    while (snowdepth > 0);
    
    cout << "Enjoy the snow!" << endl;

    cout.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Press any key to continue...." << endl;
    cout.get();

    return 0;
}

double getGallons(float snowdepth, float acrearea)
{
    const int WATER_GALLONS = 27154;
    return snowdepth * acrearea * WATER_GALLONS;
}
```